# How to add brushes on gimp

Tags: gimp

I am a new user of Ubuntu, and to be honest completly new to the whole linux scene. I'm looking to add more brushes to my GIMP program, but I don't know how.

Comment: This is borderline, but you will probably have more success in the Graphic Design SE. We generally only deal with software questions as they directly relate to photographic editing.

Comment: Are you looking for sources of brushes, or how to install them?

Comment: Or askubuntu.com (another stackexchange network site despite the separate name).

Comment: @MikeW I'm not sure either one of those would be on topic for us though.

Answer (score 4):

To add brushes to Gimp after you have downloaded them and/or opened your Zip file you need to move them to your brush folder(usually found here: C:\Documents and Settings\myusername.gimp-2.6\brushes). After you have done that you simply need to hit refresh in your brush dialog box.

You could read this which also [tutorial on installing brushes in Gimp](http://mygimptutorial.com/how-to-install-gimp-brushes).